# Updating current location instead of default?

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-places-api, mapfragment

Trying to get the app to show current location, but I don't believe it's even getting to the onConnected(). Any suggestions? I am working in a map fragment and the map appears with the default location.

```
   import android.Manifest;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
   import android.location.Location;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
   import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
   import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
   import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
   import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap; 
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

   /**
   * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
   * MapsFragment is where users will be able to select the business where they currently are and either report whether the business is hb141 compliant or if there
   * is any suspicious trafficking behavior to report.
   */

     public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

final String LOG = "HB141Log";

//Places API
Context context;
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
protected LatLng mLastLocation;

//Maps API
MapView mMapView;
GoogleMap googleMap;


public MapFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    //this segment will initialize the mapview
    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //then this segment uses the mapview to create a googlemap
    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap readyMap) {
            googleMap = readyMap;
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
            final LatLngBounds NEWENGLAND = new LatLngBounds(
                    new LatLng(41, -73), new LatLng(47, -68));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(34, 84), 6)); //defaults to atlanta
        }
    });

    //this segment initializes the googleapiclient for places api use
    buildGoogleApiClient();


    return v;
}

//callbacks for the maps api and googleapiclient
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

//callbacks for the maps api
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMapView.onLowMemory();
}

//used to build the googleapiclient
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(context)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), this)
            .build();
}




@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Location lastLocation = null;
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
    }
    if (lastLocation != null) {
        mLastLocation = new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude());
        handleNewLocation(lastLocation);
    }
}

private void handleNewLocation(Location loc) {
    double currentLatitude = loc.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = loc.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
    System.out.println("handleNewLocation ");
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
    .position(latLng)
    .title("I am here!");
    googleMap.addMarker(options);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d(LOG, "CONNECTION SUSPENDED: " + String.valueOf(i));
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(LOG, "CONNECTION FAILED: " + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
}

public void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

public void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
 //To setup location manager

 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

  //To request location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1, this);
```